# How to remove boarder and background from Material Icon Buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm setting up a new project. I've installed Angular and Material via NPM. Then I'm setting up a ToolBar from this page: https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview

I copy/pasted one of the sample toolbars:

navbar.component.html

```
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>My App</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon favorite-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with heart icon">
      <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-icon-button class="example-icon" aria-label="Example icon-button with share icon">
      <mat-icon>share</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

Layout overall looks good. But the Icon-Buttons have a border on them.

[image: Icons with borders]

They appear to be coming from the default chrome style sheet. In dev tools they have border and color properties inherited from `user agent stylesheet`

```
    background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(239, 239, 239), rgb(59, 59, 59));
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
```

I tried installing `normalize.css` thinking there was browser defaults that just needed to be set. But that didn't have any impact on this.

The docs say that `mat-icon-button` should be a round boarder with a transparent background. Did I miss something setting this up?

I created a new app with `ng new` and the only custom thing I'm doing is importing the material resources through a shared module.

The toolbar itself is in `navbar` component in my core module.

app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

Shared Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

const materialModules = [
  MatIconModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...materialModules
  ],
  exports: [...materialModules]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: you need to import MatButtonModule too

Comment: and also remove all of the styles which you have added. just include `MatButtonModule` in  `materialModules` array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

make sure you have a theme included and dont forget to import `MatButtonModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';

const materialModules = [
  MatIconModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatButtonModule
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
CommonModule,
...materialModules
  ],
  exports: [...materialModules]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```